# How to test communicator (video, sound, microphone) implemented by using WebRTC

Tags: testing, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, webrtc, selenium-grid

On my current job, we are developing an application that uses WebRTC technology.

And we want to test the work of our application with 30 users in real time -- a conference call with video, sound, and microphone (and everything must work). We know that we can do it by real users (real users connected to our application).

Question is: How to test our requirement if we don't have such a number of real persons? Maybe exists some tool for that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need a Selenium Grid.

And you'll need to build the automation part on your own on top of it.

Alternatively, you can check out https://testrtc.com -- it enables automating 100's of browsers and more with a focus on WebRTC based services.

- I am the co-founder, so take this with a grain of salt
- That said, I am not aware of any other commercial tool or otherwise that makes this as simple and straightforward

Comment: Thank you for your answer! We will investigate.

Answer (score 2):

You have two peer-reviewed IEEE scientific articles that were written on WebRTC testing state of the art this year. They both list and compare several solutions including but not limited to testRTC cited in the other answer.

On July 2017, "**WebRTC Testing: Challenges and Practical Solutions**" was published in an *IEEE venue* by the Kurento / Twilio team, and lead by the Spanish researchers that did not join Twilio but went on to start ElasTest, a millions-Euros, EU-funded project that looks very promising but is still in alpha stage.
http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7992926/.

On September 2017, "**Real-time communication testing evolution with WebRTC 1.0**" was published in *Principles, systems and Applications of IP Telecommunication* by the CoSMo team behind the original Temasys infrastructure, the symphony solution, and the new Google Testing Engine (KITE). It is a full paper about the state of the art Before google decided to go for KITE, and include a thorough review of all possible testing layers, and existing solutions. There are many solutions to do what you want today. If you need an on-premise solution, and/or test mobile browser, and/or test native apps, IoT, ... AFAIK testRTC.com will not help you, however good for other aspects.
http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8169751/.

You might want to read both articles, and citation therein before you make your choice.

Disclaimer: I am the original author of that last publication.